# Getting null array on ajax post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am passing an array(multidimensional) as a parameter to ajax call but getting null on url.

I tried using JSON.stringify and without stringify but it always returns null.

How can we fix it, TIA.

**Ajax:-**

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ filterData: myVal }),                 
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: false,
                url: "/Home/AddFilters",
                success: function (msg) {                 
                }
            });
```

**Url:-**

```
public JsonResult AddFilters(string[] filterData)
{
}
```

**Array(myVal):-**

[image: Array]

**Array after JSON.stringify:-**
[image: Array after JSON.stringify]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create model class for that, e.g.:

```
public class FilterData 
{
    public string columnName { get; set; }
    public string firstFilterType { get; set; }
    public string secondFilterType { get; set; }
    public string secondFilterVal { get; set; }
    public string multiOperator { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your *action*:

```
public JsonResult AddFilters(List<FilterData> filterData)
```

If your app is Asp.net MVC - what seems to be - it should be able to bind those values into that list parameter, which is in fact the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer suggested above by the user DontVoteMeDown will work, but in your case just removing array from string will work as below:

```
public JsonResult AddFilters(string filterData)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `contentType: 'application/json'` if you use `stringify`.
In the server side you must parser the string to JSON.